# Pandas reshaping and stacking dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet in this format:

```
Source Hour Min1  Min2  Min3
online 0    0     0     0
online 1    1     2     0
online 2    3     4     5
```

How do I use pandas to transform it to this format?

```
Hour 0                    1                    2
     Min1   Min2   Min3   Min1   Min2   Min3   Min1   Min2   Min3
     0      0      0      1      2      0      3      4      5
```

I've tried the following:

```
df= df.set_index(["Source", "Hour"])
stacked = df.stack()
```

but I got this which is almost what I need but it essentially needs to be rotated

```
Source  Hour
online  0     Min1     0
              Min2     0
              Min3     0
        1     Min1     1
              Min2     2
              Min3     0
        2     Min1     3
              Min2     4
              Min3     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `T`, notice I will recommend keep the `Source` as first level in the column

```
out = stacked.to_frame(0).T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `unstack` instead:

```
out = df.set_index(['Source','Hour']).unstack('Hour')
```

Or similarly, `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot('Source', 'Hour')
```

Output

```
          Min1       Min2       Min3      
Hour      0  1  2    0  1  2    0  1  2
Source                                 
online    0  1  3    0  2  4    0  0  5
```

To get the correct ordering as the expected output, we can do a `swaplevel` and `sort_index`:

```
out.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Hour      0              1              2          
       Min1 Min2 Min3 Min1 Min2 Min3 Min1 Min2 Min3
Source                                             
online    0    0    0    1    2    0    3    4    5
```